# Duplicity restore reports "Invalid SSH password" when I'm using a private key for connection

Tags: sftp, backup-restoration, ssh-keys, gpg, duplicity

I'm testing the restoration of a backup with duplicity 0.6.15.

I can login to my backup server just fine using ssh and sftp using the following commands and my private key:

**...sftp**

```
root@client:~# sftp -oPort=7843 backupUser@192.168.x.x
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Connected to 192.168.x.x
sftp> exit
```

**...ssh**

```
root@client:~# ssh -p7843 backupUser@192.168.x.x
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Connected to 192.168.x.x
Last Login: ....
```

I have the following restore script used to restore the contents of the signed and encrypted backup:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SIGN_PASSPHRASE='<signed-key-passphrase'
export PASSPHRASE='<encryption-passphrase>'

duplicity -v9 --encrypt-key="<encryption-key-id>" --sign-key="<signed-key-id>" --force \
scp://backupUser@192.168.x.x:7843//home/backupUser/backup /mnt/restore
```

However when I run the script duplicity:

```
root@client~#: ./restore_script.sh
```

Duplicity gives me the following error when duplicity uses it to attempt to login to my backup server:

```
Using archive dir: /root/.cache/duplicity/b1a470f45b67cd7784bc8e6449383df7
Using backup name: b1a470f45b67cd7784bc8e6449383df7
Import of duplicity.backends.hsibackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.ftpbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.botobackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.rsyncbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.imapbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.localbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.giobackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.ftpsbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.cloudfilesbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.gdocsbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.tahoebackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.u1backend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.webdavbackend Succeeded
Import of duplicity.backends.sshbackend Succeeded
Main action: restore
================================================================================
duplicity 0.6.15 (August 19, 2011)
Args: /usr/bin/duplicity -v9 --encrypt-key=<encryption-key-id> --sign-key=<signature-key-id> --force scp://backupUser@192.168.x.x:7843//home/backupUser/backup /mnt/restore
Linux client 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686
/usr/bin/python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1]
================================================================================
Using temporary directory /tmp/duplicity-sLukkP-tempdir
Registering (mkstemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-sLukkP-tempdir/mkstemp-12JD0o-1
Temp has 4995375104 available, backup will use approx 34078720.
Running 'sftp  -oPort=7843 -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 backupUser@192.168.x.x' (attempt #1)
State = sftp, Before = 'Enter'
State = sftp, Before = ''
Invalid SSH password
Running 'sftp  -oPort=7843 -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 backupUser@192.168.x.x' failed (attempt #1)
Removing still remembered temporary file /tmp/duplicity-sLukkP-tempdir/mkstemp-12JD0o-1
INT intercepted...exiting.
```

I have a public key in my `.ssh` directory, and it should allow duplicity to login using that rather than asking for an ssh-password (which I have turned off on the server anyway), so I don't understand why the server is not allowing duplicity to login.

Here's my client's listing of the `.ssh` directory, permissions and all:

```
root@client:~# ls -la /root/.ssh
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 2011-11-29 01:05 .
drwx------ 8 root root 4096 2011-11-29 12:30 ..
-rw------- 1 root root 1766 2011-11-29 01:06 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  442 2011-11-29 00:38 known_hosts
```

Is there something I'm missing?  I got the backup to work just fine, and I'd like to test out restoring the backup before sealing the deal here and saying that it works.

Comment: I even tried adding '--ssh-options="-oIdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa"' to the args... and I still get the same error.

Comment: I noticed that sftp asked me for the Passphrase to my private ssh key when I was trying to login, so why is it that duplicity doesn't use my key and just craps out instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  In order for duplicity to enter the passphrase for the ssh key, (***not*** for the gpg encryption-key), `keychain` must be installed and configured, and the key must be added using the `ssh-add` command.

I needed to install `keychain`, so I did,

and then add I added it to my `.bash_profile` like so:

```
keychain --clear id_rsa
. ~/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
```

Now assuming my public key is stored along with my private key in the `/root/.ssh` directory, when I switch users to `root` I first get an error, but after that I run `ssh-add`, `exit` out of the account, and log back in as `root` again.

When I return to the `root` account, I am asked for the ssh private key's passphrase.  Now duplicity appears to work... as far as connecting to the other server anyway...  I no longer get the `Invalid SSH Password` message I was getting earlier.

Comment: Even got the decryption working now woo!

Comment: @fuscata I will.  In a little over 17 hours according to the site.

Comment: I'm still a little unhappy with the results though as everytime I login I have to re-run the ssh-add command.  As a hack it can be added to the end of .bash_profile, but it seems like this is the wrong thing to do...